Want react-fast-marquee gradientColor set with tailwind darkMode
I have a light and dark mode toggle that works using tailwind css I want the marquee that I built with react-fast-marquee that has gradient={true} but I want the gradientColor to be set to whatever the color of the background is that the tailwind css is choosing
Background color is being chosen here
<div className="w-full h-[25vh] bg-white dark:bg-[#1a1a1a]">

i.e I want the gradientColor='white' in light mode and gradientColor='#1a1a1a' in dark mode
Here the full marquee code:
import React from 'react';
import Marquee from "react-fast-marquee";
import AWS from '../assets/icons/aws.png';
import CSS from '../assets/icons/css.png';
import REACT from '../assets/icons/react.png';
import TAILWIND from '../assets/icons/tailwind.png';
import HTML from '../assets/icons/html.png';
import JS from '../assets/icons/javascript.png';



const imageUrls = [  REACT, JS, HTML, CSS, TAILWIND, AWS,];

const Skills = () => {
    

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[25vh] bg-white dark:bg-[#1a1a1a]">
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden max-w-[1500px] mx-auto px-8 flex flex-col justify-center items-start h-full">

            <Marquee speed={30} gradient={true} gradientColor='white' autoFill={true}>
                <div className="flex justify-between">
                    {imageUrls.map((url, index) => (
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full max-w-[150px] mr-28" key={index}>
                    <img src={url} alt={`Skill ${index + 1}`} />
                    </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </Marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Here's the code to toggle light and dark:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { FiMoon, FiSun } from "react-icons/fi";

const ThemeToggle = ({ theme, setTheme }) => {
  const handleThemeSwitch = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === "dark") {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <div className="relative flex w-fit items-center rounded-full">
      <button
        className={`text-sm font-medium flex items-center gap-2 px-3 md:pl-3 md:pr-3.5 py-3 md:py-1.5 transition-colors relative z-10 ${
          theme === "light" ? "text-white" : "text-slate-300"
        }`}
        onClick={handleThemeSwitch}
      >
        <FiMoon className="relative z-10 text-lg md:text-sm" />
        <span className="relative z-10">Light</span>
      </button>
      <button
        className={`text-sm font-medium flex items-center gap-2 px-3 md:pl-3 md:pr-3.5 py-3 md:py-1.5 transition-colors relative z-10 ${
          theme === "dark" ? "text-white" : "text-slate-800"
        }`}
        onClick={handleThemeSwitch}
      >
        <FiSun className="relative z-10 text-lg md:text-sm" />
        <span className="relative z-10">Dark</span>
      </button>
      <div
        className={`absolute inset-0 z-0 flex ${
          theme === "dark" ? "justify-end" : "justify-start"
        }`}
      >
        <motion.span
          layout
          transition={{ type: "spring", damping: 15, stiffness: 250 }}
          className="h-full w-1/2 rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r from-violet-600 to-indigo-600"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ThemeToggle;

And Here's my tailwind.config
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation:{
        'infinite-scroll': 'infinite-scroll 25s linear infinite',
      }
    },
  },
  keyframes:{
    'infinite-scroll': {
      from: {transform: 'translateX(0)'},
      to: {transform: 'translateX(-100%)'},
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}

I've tried everything I could think of and it results in the gradient not having a color
